# UIStackView Peek and Pop overlay glitch

Tags: ios, uikit, uistackview, 3dtouch, peek-pop

I'm trying to implement Peek and Pop with the contents of a `UIStackView`. The problem is that the overlay (the part that isn't blurred) during the shallow press doesn't contain the right contents. It's in the right place, since it's right below my finger, but the contents seem to be taken from elsewhere in the view:[image: example]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open an empty iOS project using storyboards
2. Add a `UIStackView` to the view controller's view
3. Add nearest neighbors constraints from all four sides of the stack view equal to `0`
4. Replace the contents of `ViewController.swift` with the following code:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {
       @IBOutlet var stackView: UIStackView!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: stackView)

           let loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sed feugiat ligula. Sed in rutrum lacus, vel auctor felis. Vivamus molestie felis nisi. Mauris euismod eros vitae libero commodo porttitor. Nam posuere, dui vitae aliquam mollis, quam mauris tempus turpis."

           let label = UILabel()
           label.numberOfLines = 0
           label.text = repeatElement(loremIpsum, count: 4).joined(separator: "\n\n")
           stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
       }
   }

   extension ViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
       func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
           previewingContext.sourceRect = CGRect(x: location.x - 50, y: location.y - 50, width: 100, height: 100)
           return storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController()
       }

       func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
           present(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true)
       }
   }
   ```
5. Run the app on your (physical) device and force touch anywhere

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in UIKit?

Edit: This is how I expected it to behave: [image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing

```
registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: stackView)
```

by

```
registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: view)
```

solved the problem. I still suspect that it's a bug, but at least this is a workaround.

Comment: Ran into this bug separately on iOS 11.4, but I think it was fixed in iOS 12.